# Allow only one space between words in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to do a validation in windows form for allow only one space between the text values. How to do in c#. Thanks in advance.
I don't want to use any other method for this validation only in c#. Please help me to do this.

```
if (e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space)) 
    { 
    MessageBox.Show("Spaces are not allowed at start"); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `if (string.Join(" ", test.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) != test) ... // bad spacing`

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

```
string str = "words   with multiple         spaces";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.None);     
str = regex.Replace(str, @" "); // "words with multiple spaces"
```

Answer (score 0):

get your string length and then test each character if it is a white space or not. if it has more than 1 white space, make your function fail.

```
String myString = "My String";
int myStringLength = myString.length;
int nrOfSpaces = 0;

for(i = 0; i <= myStringLength)
{
   if(myString[i] == " ")
   {
      nrofspaces++;
      i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: this only works for two words... what if the input has 3 words? Then there are (correctly) two spaces.

Comment: No, It counts all of the spaces in the string.